# removed rows containing NA values in a specific column Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

I have a data contains 12 variables "columns" and 1200 rows. In 4th variable "column", many missing values "NA", so I want to remove all the rows that have NA value in the 4th column.
Note: the 4th column is: age     : num  22 38 26 35 35 NA 54 2 27 14 ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with a data frame, you can try simply subsetting off the rows you don't want using the `is.na()` function.  Something like this:

```
df <- df[!is.na(df[,4]), ]
```